# How to get some portion in the url?

Tags: php

I am working in php. I want to get some portion of the url using php,

For Example, my url is "http://localhost:82/index.php?route=product/product&path=117&product_id=2153". i want route=product/product only.

Comment: thanks its work fine for me.

Comment: Might be a good time to get cozy with a good tutorial or two.

Answer (score 3):

Since the variable might not exist, you could (and should) ensure your code does not trigger notices with:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['route'])) {
    $route = $_GET['route'];
}else{
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to skip manual index checks and maybe add further validations you can use the [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) extension:

```
<?php
 echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'route');
```

You can read it using $_REQUEST as below:

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['route'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like simply `$_GET['route']` will work, although that will only give you `product/product`. You can just fill in the rest yourself if you know the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Those URL parameters are called get variables.  You can retrieve them using the super global `$_GET` like so

```
$route = $_GET['route'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?php
     $ans=$_GET['route'];
     echo $ans;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code,

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["route"]))
    echo $_REQUEST['route'];

?>
```